# How to add minutes to the time part of datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, time, dateadd

How to add `minutes(INT)` to the time part of `datetime` ?

For example :

If I have datetime variable like this :

```
  @shift_start_time =  2015-11-01 08:00:00.000

  @increase = 30
```

How to get this result?

```
2015-11-01 08:30:00.000
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use **[`DATEADD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**:

```
SELECT DATEADD(mi, @increase,   @shift_start_time);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a2787bd91f6984645276b795aa7f09fe)**

Answer (score 23):

Using dateadd:

```
DATEADD(minute,@increase,@shift_start_time)
```

the first argument can be chosen among:
year
quarter
month
dayofyear
day
week
weekday
hour
minute
second
millisecond
microsecond
nanosecond

please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 3):

To add minutes to the time part of datetime =>

```
SELECT DATEADD("mi", @increase,   @shift_start_time);
```

Comment: How does this differ from or add to the already accepted answer?

Comment: Explicitly stating that the first argument is a string.