# How to update System_Timestamp in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `tableA` with a timestamp column as shown below

```
T_SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP
--------------------------
2021-08-05 17:42:05.386000
2021-08-25 11:17:31.776000
2021-08-25 11:19:12.612000
```

How can I manually changed all the timestamp values to say, `2021-01-01`?

In SQL developer I can simply just do the following command for timestamps

```
update tableA 
set t_system_timestamp = t_system_timestamp - 30;
```

Since for SQL Server timestamp is not an int I can't do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From the tool tip *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." This means that at least 2 people agree with that tooltip. Downvotes aren't toxic; never have been, never will be·

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add minutes to the time part of datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760529/how-to-add-minutes-to-the-time-part-of-datetime/33760542)

Comment: Hi Larnu, I don't understand how I can show my research efforts in a question? Because believe me I did some research (I even added the sql developer command which I found but could not find the mssql equivalent). Forgive me for not being good with mssql as I've only just started learning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `dateadd()`:

```
update tableA
    set t_system_timestamp = dateadd(day, -30, t_system_timestamp);
```